# Finding number of nodes in PHP, DOM, XPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am loading HTML into DOM and then querying it using XPath in PHP. My current problem is how do I find out how many matches have been made, and once that is ascertained, how do I access them?

I currently have this dirty solution:

```
$i = 0;  
foreach($nodes as $node) {  
    echo $dom->savexml($nodes->item($i));  
    $i++;
}
```

Is there a cleaner solution to find the number of nodes, I have tried count(), but that does not work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You haven't posted any code related to `$nodes` so I assume you are using DOMXPath and query(), or at the very least, you have a [DOMNodeList](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).
DOMXPath::query() returns a DOMNodeList, which has a length member. You can access it via (given your code):

```
$nodes->length
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know the count, you can also use [`DOMXPath::evaluate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php).

Example from PHP Manual:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('book.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$tbody = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tbody')->item(0);

// our query is relative to the tbody node
$query = 'count(row/entry[. = "en"])';
$entries = $xpath->evaluate($query, $tbody);
echo "There are $entries english books\n";
```